# Testing JavaScript Example on MDN

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I found the following JavaScript example here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

```
/**
 * Example 2
 */
// will return a value of undefined
var myvar = "my value";

(function() {
  console.log(myvar); // undefined
  var myvar = "local value";
})();
```

Why does  `console.log(myvar)` return `"my value"` and not `undefined` as specified in the comment?

I tested it in Firefox and Chrome and I get the same result.

Comment: Are you sure? http://jsfiddle.net/kRpTh/

Comment: It's always a better idea to test things like this on a real page (like jsbin or jsfiddle, or your own test page) and not just the console. That said, pasting that code into my Firefox console logs `undefined` as promised.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/kXWXu/ it outputs "my value"

Comment: @mt22: Well sure. You changed the code to remove `var`. Adding/removing keywords changes behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myvar = "my value";

(function() {
  console.log(myvar); // undefined   
  var myvar = "local value";
})();​
```

Indeed, the output is undefined.
I think it's because myvar is redefined in the scope.

But if you comment myvar in the function scope, output will be "my value".
Like if myvar is a global variable.

--> [Try !](http://jsfiddle.net/zJ2fG/)

Answer (score 1):

Its fiddle, created by **xdazz** similar to your post -> [local variable declaration](http://jsfiddle.net/kRpTh)

In your fiddle you don't redeclare `myvar` as local variable, just reset its value
[global variable change value](http://jsfiddle.net/kXWXu)

```
var myvar = "local value";//redeclared variable as local
myvar = "local value";//reset global value
```